What kind of concrete repair material should I use to fix this peeling patch in a sloped drain that is puddling water?

How should I fix this drain slope that was patched and now has a high spot, making the water pool and soak under the peeling patch instead of making it to the drain?  I'm a DIY'er so would be looking for the easiest - idiot proof way that doesn't require great skill.
Should I use chisel out edges of the old patch and do a new vinyl patch and try to feather it out, or should I use a concrete resurfacer?  If so, how can I prevent self-leveling to maintain the drain slope?  Ideally it would be something that wouldn't crack or peel away as easily if there is any movement in the soil underneath.
Should I just hire a professional?  If so, what should they be using?

Why is there a vinyl patch, (or whatever it is) if there is dirt under the concrete?  It makes no sense unless there is something else there that is unknown.

it's about 4" of concrete and then earth underneath, but the basin is about a foot deep .. there used to be a smaller 2 " yard drain there before they replaced it with a catch basin.

remove the patch start over

If it's not loose. Grind off the high part with a stone grinding wheel in an angle grinder, wear a dusk mask, hearing, and eye protection protection.
If it is loose chisel it out and do it again. I see other cracks it may be worth redoing a larger patch, or even the whole floor.
